# RealityKit - Can I make a RealityKit Entity's material with SwiftUI View?

Tags: swiftui, arkit, realitykit

Is it possible to augment SwiftUI view in AR World? I need a SwiftUI button view inside AR world. Is it possible to make material of a RealityKit Entity with SwiftUI View?

How can I get clickable SwiftUI button inside AR World?

**(Not as a z index over ARViewContainer)**

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to put a SwiftUI button into AR as it requires a totally different rendering system. If you want, you could create an AR ModelEntity (that looks like a SwiftUI button) and assign it an action when the user taps on it.

Comment: I ended up creating ModelEntity with image that looks like button then added collision component on it to handle tap gesture.